# How do i consuming rest service with jquery in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, monaca

I am using monaca IDE + phonegap to build a phone app.

I have created a restful server  - http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1

And i am trying to consume the json rest service with this jquery script in my js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1"
}).then(function(data) {
   $('.ch-name').append(data.ch_name);
   $('.ch_logo').append(data.ch_logo);
});
```

});

and calling it it in the body like this

```
    <div>
<p class="ch_logo"> </p>
<p class="ch_name"> </p>
</div>
```

should this not be working?  I have included the jquery.min.js file and the ajax file to the page . but it just wont show a thing.

Comment: Did you check the console for any error message? Try log the data in the promisse function. (console.log(data) in .then.)

Comment: Please am new to jquery. I only know  a bit about javascript , so its quit impossible for me to write the right syntax to log the data input . I can do that in javascript though . Anyway , my unedited code has no errors when i checked . the only thing , like you suggested , is to check the data if its streaming in . thank you

Comment: Maybe you are having cross domain conflicts? I tried to run the code and received: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1?_=1435681247893. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access. Read this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: I can run the url on my pc without any problem. i visit the site directly . Anyway , i changed the  javascript code a bit  ... it said success. but nothing shows in my app .  ` $(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url:  "http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1",
    data: "[]",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
}).then(function(data) {
      $('.ch-name').append(data.ch_name);
      $('.ch-logo').append(data.ch_logo);
   });
 }); `

Comment: I also just checked what you just sent . i added the domain origin . but still!!!! by default it was even granting access to all domains.

Comment: i just logged the data and i got [object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object]

Comment: You are receiving an array, give me a second and i post a answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
      url: "http://engridmedia.com/next/api/channel/user/id/1",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Failed!');
    },
}).then(function(data) {
    var result = data [0];
    console.log(result)
    $('.ch-name').append(result.ch_name);
    $('.ch-logo').append(result.ch_logo);
});
});
```

You are returning a **object** in a **array**. You need to get the **first** object in that array.

Comment: wow thank you bro . thank you very much !!!!  You missed  "  }); " at the end though . thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!                                                                   How can i list all the data at once?  a foreach  in javascript will do ?

Comment: Actually you have only one element in the array. If you have more you can do a for in javascript. If the answer helped y apreciate you mark as positive.

Comment: i did appreciate it but the site said i need to earn some reputation first  before it will show . lol Gracias Amigo! Good luck to argentina today.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with the app!